# when I use Server.Transfer it Shows the source of HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, module

I wrote a C# code in an HTTP Module for redirection in an ASP.Net project.

When I use Server.Transfer to redirect to an HTML page, it shows the source code of page. But I want to see the own page.

```
string finalAddress = "/MyPage.html";
HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(finalAddress, true);
```

What's the problem???

Comment: Why not use `Response.Redirect("/MyPage.html")`?

Comment: Because I wanna keep the original address in the browser, but show the target page.